# How to suppress qplot's binwidth warning inside a function?

Tags: r, ggplot2, warnings, suppress-warnings

I am writing a function that uses `qplot()` to draw a histogram, for example,

```
> library(ggplot2)
> d=rnorm(100)
> myfun=function(x) qplot(x)
```

Running it gives a warning:

```
> myfun(d)
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
```

To suppress the warning, I tried computing the binwidth myself, but this gives an error and doesn't plot:

```
> myfun=function(x) print(qplot(x, binwidth=diff(range(x))/30))
> myfun(d)
Error in diff(range(x)) : object 'x' not found
```

I have two related questions:

- What is going on here? Why is object 'x' not found?
- How can I write the function so the warning is not generated?

Thanks!

Comment: If you do `myfun(as.data.frame(d))` then `qplot(d, data=x, binwidth=diff(range(d))/30)` it works. So it looks like the `binwidth` argument is evaluated strictly in the context of the given data frame.  Not sure if that's a feature or a bug.

Comment: The question isn't how to suppress the message inside a function but how to suppress it at all. e.g., `suppressMessages(qplot(rnorm(10)))` still gives the message.

Comment: @Daniel - the problem seems to be platform or version dependent. Your solution works for me on a Mac using R 2.12.1 and ggplot2 0.8.9 but it does not work on Windows with R 2.13.0 and ggplot2 0.8.9. Unfortunately Windows is my target platform.

Comment: @Kevin - outside a function I can compute binwidth and it suppresses the message, the problem is with the calculation of binwidth inside a function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can't explain the *why* of this one (Hadley may swing by and do so) but using `ggplot` instead of `qplot` solves the problem:

```
d <- data.frame(v1 = rnorm(100))
myfun <- function(x){
    p <- ggplot(data = x, aes(x = v1)) + 
                    geom_histogram(binwidth = diff(range(x$v1))/30)
    print(p)
}
```

Doing it this way I get no warning message. Also, using `ggplot` and removing the `binwidth = ...` portion in `geom_histogram` makes the warning reappear, but then `suppressMessages` works as expected as well.

I suspect this has to do with namespaces or environments and when/where `qplot` and `ggplot` are evaluating arguments. But again, that's just a guess...

Answer (score 11):

To attempt to clear up some confusion, this construct does not prevent the binwidth warnings/messages to appear:

```
suppressMessages(p <- ggplot(...))
print(p)
```

But this does:

```
p <- ggplot(...)
suppressMessages(print(p))
```

As Hadley's comment points out, lazy evaluation prevents the `stat_*` functions from actually running until they need to at print-time.

Comment: For those using gridExtra, the evaluation happens in the arrangeGrob call, not the grid.draw call. So you need suppressMessages(arrangeGrob(...)). I wasted some time figuring this out.

Answer (score 1):

As they say on TV "Had this been a real warning you would have been given directions from your local authorities."

Since it wasn't a warning then my original answer didn't cause it to error out. This is what I should have written:

```
options(warnings= -1)
<do something> # no warnings
options(warnngs=1)
<business as usual>
```

But it wasn't a warning but a message to the console. Here's how to stop it:

```
 con=file("temp.fil", "w")
 sink(con, type="message")
 library(ggplot2)
  d=rnorm(100)
  myfun=function(x) qplot(x)
  myfun(d)
 sink( type="message")
```

Comment: This does not suppress the binwidth warning.

Comment: It's NOT a warning. It's a message that the plot function is sending. If you wnat to suck it up you need to use `sink` or `capture.output`.

Comment: If using suppressMessages worked, then Kevin might have reported success and I would not have posted.